# Why is the LinkedList.data null after returning from an insert?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

First of all, this is part of a homework assignment, so please keep that in mind when answering.

So I am attempting to use a generic LinkedList class, which a CustomerList class inherits from. All code below is written by me and not given as part of the assignment.

I have written the customer type, which works successfully. The code shouldn't be needed, as the problem does not have to do with that class. It has 3 int fields, and a method to print it's info.

```
    public void printCustomerInfo() {
    System.out.println([int field 1, 2, 3]);
    }
```

The issue has to do with the insert method (I believe) of the generic LinkedList class. It takes in a object of the determined class, and inserts it in the list in front of the current LinkedList object. 
It does this by creating a copy of the current LinkedList object, setting that as the nextList, and then modifying the data of the current LinkedList object to the given dataIn.
Here is the code for the LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    T data;
    protected LinkedList<?> nextList;

    public LinkedList() {
        data = null;
        nextList = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (null == nextList);
    }

    public LinkedList<?> getNextList() {
        return nextList;
    }

    public void insert(T dataIn) {
        System.out.println("dataIn passed to insert method: \t" + dataIn);
        LinkedList<T> tempList = new LinkedList<T>();
        tempList.data = this.data;
        tempList.nextList = this.nextList;
        this.nextList = tempList;
        this.data = dataIn;
        System.out.println("data field of current object: \t\t" + data);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T delete() {
        T tempDump = data;
        data = (T) nextList.data;
        nextList = nextList.nextList;
        return tempDump;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("-END-");
        } else {
            System.out.println(data);
            nextList.printInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

The CustomerList class extends it, and sets the data type to customer.
Here is the code:

```
public class CustomerList extends LinkedList<Customer> {
    Customer data;

    public void printInfo() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("-END-");
        } else {
            data.printCustomerInfo();
            nextList.printInfo();
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, the testing object:

```
public class GeneralTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Test LinkedList class
        System.out.println(" - Create CustomerList and test methods");
        CustomerList rList = new CustomerList();

        System.out.println(" - Create a customer to store in the list");
        Customer dude = new Customer(10, 65);
        dude.setTimeServed(120);

        System.out.println("proof that customer object exists: \t" + dude);

        System.out.println(" - Insert customer into the list");

        System.out.println("---method call: insert---");
        rList.insert(dude);
        System.out.println("---method end: insert----");

        System.out.println("data in the list after return: \t\t" + rList.data);
    }
}
```

This is what the console prints:

```
 - Create CustomerList and test methods
 - Create a customer to store in the list
proof that customer object exists:  assignment3.Customer@3c250cce
 - Insert customer into the list
---method call: insert---
dataIn passed to insert method:     assignment3.Customer@3c250cce
data field of current object:   assignment3.Customer@3c250cce
---method end: insert----
data in the list after return:  null
```

As far as I can tell/understand, it is a scoping problem. Perhaps I am assigning the variable at a level that is ignored as the method resolves. I have run onto a similar issue before, and was able to resolve it, but cannot figure this out. Unfortunately, my prof is out town for next couple days, so I am looking for help here.

I just tried to make a method that simply sets the data field to a passed in object:

```
public void setData(T dataIn) {
    this.data = dataIn;
}
```

Even this did not change the data from null. I know this must be due to not understanding Java generics correctly, so any pointers you can give, (and online resources to read) would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint.  If you declare a data member in both the parent LinkedList class, and in the child class, the child member will overshadow the parent class's version.

Comment: Of Course! Because the LinkedList class uses generics, there is no need to overwrite the parent's data attribute. The extension of the LinkedList class defines the type through the "LinkedList<Customer>" expression.

I had thought originally that the "Customer data" would act as the type definition. Instead, it just hid the wanted data field, and made it inaccessible by outside functions.

So it wasn't that the data field was being changed to null as i first thought, but instead was just hidden by a different data field that WAS null.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice reasoning!  I wanted to get you started in the right direction, since you said it was homework.